# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [UserControl] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm currently working on a todo list project for my school and im trying to create a UserControl method called showUser. I need it to be able to show the user a dd('hello'); display but when run it brings
TARGET CLASS(UserControl) does not exist

In need of assistance your help will be greatly appraeciated. Thank you.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserControl extends Controller
{
    

        public function showUsers()
        {
           return view('home');
        }


}
//this is the UserControl.php controller
```

//and this is the web.php route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\http\request;

Route::get('/', [UserControl::class, 'showUsers']);
```

//this is my controller.php file in the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

//this is the master.blade.php file in the views folder

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>My Application</title>
        </head>
        <body>








 @yield('content')









 @yield('scripts')

        </body>
    </html>
```

//and finally this is the home.blade.php file in the view folder

```
@extends('includes.master')




@section('content')

{{$channel}}


@endsection






@section('scripts')

<script>
    
</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 4):

The class you are using `UserControl::class` in the file `web.php` represents a class at root namespace `\UserControl::class` and not your target `\App\Http\Controllers\UserControl::class`. To define it as such, give it the full namespace or (if used multiple times) set the `use` directive.

In your web.php use the full namespace

```
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\UserControl::class, 'showUsers']);
```

Or set it in the use;

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserControl;

Route::get('/', [UserControl::class, 'showUsers']);
```

Comment: keeps bringing this as an error                                                                                                                                                                       Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [UserControl] does not exist.

Comment: Maybe you have set the route cache in place, try running `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan route:cache` after the modification